# SFML program crashes

Tags: c++, crash, sfml, clion

I recently downloaded SFML Library on my windows 10 machine and I'm trying to statically link library to my project, but i'm getting this error.

```
CMake Error at C:/SFML/cmake/Modules/FindSFML.cmake:358 (message):
  SFML found but some of its dependencies are missing ( FreeType libjpeg
  OpenAL Ogg Vorbis VorbisFile VorbisEnc FLAC)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package)
```

The thing is, in documentation it says:

> On Windows and Mac OS X, all the needed dependencies are provided
>   directly with SFML, so you don't have to download/install anything.
>   Compilation will work out of the box.

I also checked and found required libraries in SFML/lib. But for some reasons cmake can't find them. Here's the CMakeList:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(Orc_Group_assig)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(Orc_Group_assig ${SOURCE_FILES})
set(SFML_ROOT C:/SFML)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "C:/SFML/cmake/Modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
add_definitions(-DSFML_STATIC)
set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES ON)
find_package(SFML 2.3.2 REQUIRED  graphics window network audio system )
if(SFML_FOUND)
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(Orc_Group_assig ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
    target_link_libraries(Orc_Group_assig ${SFML_DEPENDECIES})
else()
    message("FREAKING ERROR")
endif()
```

What should I do to make it work ?

Comment: I assume it only happens when you close the window? After you close the window, how would the other functions you call on the window object work?

Comment: It happens before window even opens

Comment: Are DLLs correctly located ?

Comment: they're all in `SFML/bin`

Comment: didn't work. it still crashes

Comment: *Where* does it crash? Have you tried running in a debugger to locate where (in your code) it happens?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066330/mingw-sfml-giving-error-code

SFML too, same error code, you should try was is said in the solution.

(moving the dlls in the executable directory)